# Checking for Overfitting and Underfitting in sklearn models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using the sklearn `RandomForestClassifier` as my classification. I could not figure out how to get evaluate Overfitting and Underfitting for sklearn models.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=1, criterion='entropy', bootstrap=True, oob_score=True, verbose=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Currently, I am using other metrics to evaluate my model like - cross_val_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, PermutationImportance. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: This is really more of a question on statistical learning than it's a question on sklearn: If you understand `cross_val_score`, chances are you also understand why cross-validation is useful, and in particular how that can give you a useful estimate on generalization error. If not, you could start by diving into cross-validation (which will be discussed in any primer on learning), then only afterwards see how the relevant methods appear natively in sklearn.

Comment: are you clear about the concept of Over fitting and Under fitting?have any test data or validation data

Comment: Yes, I am. I wanted to know if you can find training errors and testing errors while using sklearn models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can test overfitting and underfitting.  If you want to look specifically at train and test scores and compare them you can do this with sklearns [cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate).  If you read the documentation it will return you a dictionary with train scores (if supplied as train_score=True) and test scores in metrics that you supply.

sample code

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=1, criterion='entropy', bootstrap=True, oob_score=True, verbose=1)
cv_dict = cross_validate(model, X, y, return_train_score=True)
```

You can also simply create a hold out test set with train test split and compare your training and test scores using the test data set.